# How to get a specific document from couchdb using c#

Tags: c#, couchdb

Im trying to get a specific document from my couchDB using c#.

The request URL looks like this.

```
http://localhost:5984/db/_design/ImportJobs/_view/ImportJob?include_docs=true&group=false&attachments=false&att_encoding_info=false&inclusive_end=true&key={"ImportJob":{"ImportJobId":"728db88d-7cc0-4853-ad60-9b5324eff1cd"}}&sorted=true&stable=false&update=true&update_seq=false
```

this just returns this metadata. No documents, and not one but 5 documents.

[image: Only Metadata]

My view looks like this.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/ImportJobs",
  "_rev": "23-8fedf6e13192b355414639a11beb29b2",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "ImportJobs": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\r\n    if (doc.Type) {\r\n        if (doc.Type == \"ImportJob\" && doc._deleted !== true) {\r\n            emit(doc.CustomerId, doc._id);\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n"
    },
    "ImportJob": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\r\n    if (doc.Type) {\r\n        if (doc.Type == \"ImportJob\" && doc._deleted != true) {\r\n            emit(doc.ImportJob.ImportJobId, doc._id);\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n"
    }
  },
  "updates": {},
  "filters": {}
}
```

Can someone see where the problem is.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Consider updating the question with an example of the response JSON

Comment: It appears you want to use a `_find` selectors for the key.  That does not work with views. Just do `key=728db88d-7cc0-4853-ad60-9b5324eff1cd` for example.

Comment: Hey Ramblin Rose. Thankyou for your response. The middle picture is the response json. Thankyou for your example, ill try it out.

Comment: Thankyou Ramblin Rose. With a little correction your suggestion was perfect. The correction was key="728db88d-7cc0-4853-ad60-9b5324eff1cd".